# How to connect with SSH2 and public keys with “sudo” permissions

Tags: ssh, php, sudo

I'm doing a computer security application for GNU / LINUX in Symfony 3.4. but when connecting to PCs I can execute any command, except those that require root permissions, obtaining the following error:

```
Error: LW_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED [code 0x00009cde] Incorrect access attempt
```

and the connection is with password in plane:

```
@ssh2_auth_password($connection, "$username", "mi-password")
```

I need to connect surely with public and private keys generated with shh-keygen but when trying it, it is never connected even by the console of the PC. And when executing sudo su or sudo commands I receive an error because you can not insert the password that you request from the web. In summary what I need is to connect with keys and that user with keys is guaranteed root or sudo access without requesting a password. I've heard something about PAM but it's not easy to understand. I need help. Thanks in advance.